# TFS WorkItem Excel Attachment open and update directly

Tags: excel, tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to keep updating Excel Attachment in TFS 2017. Right now i have to download, open excel, Update and then Save excel. Then delete existing attachment and then upload the recently updated copy of attachment. This is tedious process and error prone. 
Can we either

1. Directly open Excel attachment in browser, Update and save directly from browser
2. Open Excel in Excel app but connected to TFS and can be Auto Saved after update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not able to be achieved in Work Item attachment. But you can create an Excel workbook in office 365, and then add Hyperlink in the work item. In this way, when you click the link, you can open the workbook in browser, update and save directly from browser.

[image]

Or you can add the Excel workbook into source control, and link versioned item in Work Item, then you can update the excel locally and check it into TFS.

Comment: Yes it is one solution. Its just it wont fit in my situation. But I really liked the solution. Thanks